# Colored completion buffer when opening files

Tags: completion, colors

As you all know when you hit C-x C-f and then TAB to auto-complete, an auto-completion window pops-up. But does anyone know how to get the list of files colored by type (eg. folder in blue, files in white or whatever) ? Like in the normal shell ?

Apparently it is possible to do it with Helm but I am not using helm myself (maybe I should try it though).

Thanks !

Comment: `C-x C-f TAB` does not auto-complete with vanilla Emacs. If you are using a particular library or mode, such as `auto-complete-mode`, please say so as part of the problem description - e.g., provide a recipe.

Comment: +1 to trying Helm. Once you're used to it, you'll find it hard to use Emacs without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this librairy: https://github.com/vjohansen/emacs-config/blob/master/site-lisp/color-file-completion.el

The biggest problem is that you lost `completions-first-difference`.